# Оптимизация геометрии (Batches)

Tags: c#, unity3d, vr

Делаю первый раз такой большой проект на 3D, я новичок с оптимизацией, но многое прочел.
Batches: 3300, так было без оптимизации, что я делал:
1. Occlusion;
2. удалил ненужные объекты(части);
3. уменьшил используемые материалы;
4. выставил оптимальные шейдера и размер текстур.
Так же искал Mesh Combiner, нашел один, только он применяет всего один материал/текстуру, целый объект одного цвета, объединил все объекты которые возможно было. 
На данный момент в фронтальном виде персонажа, батчи = 800, с левой правой стороны  от персонажа было замерено около 250-300. Схему строения предоставил ниже в скринах.
Теперь вопрос, есть бесплатный Mesh Baker, который адекватно осуществляет слияние мешей не теряя текстуры / материалов ? использую Unity 2017.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdLGe.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIGy6.jpg

Comment: У тебя случаем галочка Gizmos не включена?(рядом с Stats в Game окне) 686 Setpass многовато

Comment: нет, с ней 900, использую UI панели и пустышки для определения дистанций

Comment: Какой ассет combine вы использовали? Что значит не теряя текстур и материалов?(в основе уменьшения batches лежит уменьшение материалов и обьединение текстур в атласы, сколько меши не комбинируй это не поможет). По вашим 686 setpass могу сказать, что у вас огромное количество материалов и шейдеры там больше, чем с одним проходом(pass).

Comment: Использовал этот http://u3d.at.ua/load/skripty/simple_mesh_combine/2-1-0-1930 
Допустим два квадрата, фиолетовый и коричневый, я объединяю их, и на выходе у меня одна фигура, с коричневым цветом, с текстурами так же

Comment: Могу посоветовать Draw Call Minimizer из бесплатных